# Atom UI issues after installation and reinstallation

Tags: user-interface, text-editor, atom-editor

I am having issues with using Atom text-editor. I have used it before on my system and all was fine. However, opening it today, I had the UI looking like this:

[image: Atom GUI]

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it, but to no avail. I have also deleted the local data file after installation and I keep getting the same UI.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What UI do you expect to see? As Dan mentions in his answer below, your screenshot is a normal Atom view with debug panels open; nothing appears to be broken.

Comment: what packages are you using? apm list --installed --bare > package-list.txt

Comment: I managed to fix it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42822923/4422282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I was not expecting the above layout after a fresh reinstall. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WcpL.jpg) was what I expected (and am used to).

Somehow the .atom folder in C:\Users\%USER%.atom was completely hidden and read only, so I had trouble locating it. After using the terminal to access the folder, I inspected discovered its properties. After removing the hidden and read-only attributes, I deleted the folder and reinstalled Atom and it managed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to get rid of the panel(s) at the right side of the window, that is your debug console. Just click the "x" at the upper right corner (in the light-gray section, not in the application title bar) and it will go away.

If that is not what you meant, you need to clarify the question.